# Transforming into polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

Transform this into a polynomial:
$-x^2+6x-9$

Is there a formula?

What number $k^2$ can be a negative
number?

I thought that only $-k ^{(odd number)}$ could be negative, but it is a binomial so...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why did you tag this [tag:linear-algebra]?  $-x^2+6x-9$ *is* a polynomial (it's $-(x-3)^2$, by the way)

Comment: Because I didn't know any other tag, sorry!

Comment: Thanks by the way, Tanner

Comment: Tags [tag:polynomial], [tag:quadratics], and/or [tag:algebra-precalculus] would be more appropriate

Comment: $k^2$ can be a negative number for some $k = a + b \sqrt{-1} = a + b \cdot i$ (i.e. a [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)). Note that your polynomial $-x^2+6x-9 = -(x^2-6x+9)$ transforms to $-(x-3)^2 = - (k^2)$, not $k^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Right, for any real number its square is never negative. However, a good trick when the $x^2$ term is negative is to factor out a $-1$. Here we now have $$-(x^2-6x+9).$$

Then, you simply factor $x^2-6x+9 = (x-3)^2$, so the answer becomes $-(x-3)^2$.

-FruDe